# DELETE method interpreted as GET method in Rails 7 logout link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I'm writing an app in rails 7. I added a devise for Users. When I click on the logout link, a GET request is being sent instead of DELETE.

My link looks like this

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, id: "logout-link" %>
```

I tried doing the following:

```
yarn add @rails/ujs
```

Then in my application.js

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
Rails.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

UJS and using `link_to ... method: :delete` is deprecated for Rails 7, so rather than trying to diagnose your UJS issue, just [use `button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Rails 7 uses Turbo by default, and Turbo doesn't understand DELETE requests. So when you click on the logout link, Turbo sees a DELETE request and converts it to a GET request.

To fix this, you can do one of the following:

Change the HTTP method for the sign out route from DELETE to GET in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

You can also use the `data-turbo-method` attribute on the link. This tells Turbo to use the specified HTTP method for the request.

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
```

In your case, since you have already installed `@rails/ujs`, you can use the `data-turbo-method` attribute. So the updated code for your link would be:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { turbo_method: :delete }, id: "logout-link" %>
```

Comment: Hmm, `method: :delete` and `data: { turbo_method: :delete }` simultaneously?

Comment: Oddly enough, yes. On two separate occasions, I had an instance where having both would make code work properly and removing one lead to an error. But I probably need to mention that just having method: :delete should be enough at the end of the day

Comment: I had a similar issue, and adding "data: { turbo_method: :delete }" does address it (thanks @borisano).  I hope that in future versions we can go back to the simpler syntax of just "method: :delete" - now that turbo is the default mechanism for handling this.